# Is "did you" pronounced /di ju:/, /di dʒju:/ or /di dju:/?

Tags: pronunciation

There are 3 types of pronunciation of "did you" I've heard, /di ju:/, /di dʒju:/ and /di dju:/.

When a speaker, usually an American, doesn't pronounce the second 'd', that would be /di ju:/.

When a speak pronounces the second 'd', an American like pronouncing /di dju:/, and a British like pronouncing /di dʒju:/.

Is my understanding right?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how informally you are speaking (some would say, lazily) whether or not you pronounce the second 'd'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are 3 types of pronunciation of "did you" I've heard, /di ju:/, /di dʒju:/ and /di dju:/.

I've never heard anyone pronounce *did you* as /di ju:/. It might happen in fast speech but you should definitely not aim for it.

/di dʒju:/ is the pronunciation of *did you* in normal/ casual speech.

In *did you*, sometimes the /d/ of did and /j/ (y) of *you* assimilate to /dʒ/. The process is called [assimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology)).

It's because when you articulate /j/ immediately after /d/, the [place of articulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place_of_articulation) becomes very similar to that of /dʒ/ so it sounds like /dʒ/.

See [Yod-coalescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters)

And /di dju:/ is the normal pronunciation of *did you* (without assimilation).

---

> When a speaker, usually an American, doesn't pronounce the second 'd', that would be /di ju:/.

It's not restricted to AmE or BrE. It can happen in all varieties of English. And once again, eliding the d from *did* is very informal and I've never heard it.